# Problem with Hebrew charset in send_DbMail used in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

Using SQL2016 SSIS for single action: send email using send_DbMail procedure.
The SQL server installed in English with Hebrew localization.

The @subject & @body contain Hebrew, and the body is HTML formated. when executing an sql job with a code to send the email - it sent OK.

If I create SSIS package, test it on my PC - email sent OK.

If I upload the package from my PC to my SSIS server and run it in sql job - the email will be non readable (both subject & body).

Testing the all_mailitems query show the data is not recognized before exit to exchange.

Why there is a difference between 2 sql jobs types (direct code & SSIS package)? any idea how to configure the SSIS server to recognize Hebrew?

Sample code:

```
    Declare @myHtml as nvarchar(max)
    set @myHtml = N'<html><body><H1>בדיקה בדיקה</H1></body></html>'
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile = 'MyProfile',
    @recipients ='MyEmail',
    @Subject = N'מייל בדיקה',
    @body = @myHtml,
    @body_format = 'html'
```

Comment: If it's non-readable it means you're using ASCII (varchar) text instead of `nvarchar` (Unicode). Don't use `varchar` for non-English text. I'd bet the production server uses a non-Hebrew collation resulting in mangled ASCII text. Another possibility is that the query used to produce the email is converting the text to ASCII. That would be the case if the query was created through string concatenation

Comment: SO itself is proof there are no special requirements for Unicode. It's an ASP.NET application that stores text in `nvarchar` columns without any special encoding or decoding. That's why I can type `Αυτό εδώ` and be certain it's going to show properly

Comment: I'm using nvarchar(max) , the server collation is hebrew, and there is a difference in the result if i execute an sql query in Job or SSIS package in Job

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the specifics of how you are invoking the `sp_send_dbmail` ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce any problems. After replacing `@profile` with `@profile_name` I was able to send the message to a GMail account and receive it without problem. The subject header was sent as UTF8 which some old email clients may not like.

What I received contained this :

```
Subject: מייל בדיקה
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+PEgxPteR15PXmden15Qg15HXk9eZ16fXlDwvSDE+PC9ib2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=
```

Which was rendered correctly by GMail. The decoded Base64 string is identical to the original body.

Email headers like `Subject` [had to use MIME encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_email) for non-ASCII text in the past. [RFC6532](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6532) finally allowed UTF8

Comment: You sent it by ssis package on ssis server 2016? If yes then what were your sever settings ?